# Read CSV file it include several numbers

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, data-cleaning, read.csv

I have a data like this and for male and female column, I just need the first row (highlited ones). Could you please how can I read just these numbers and exclude rests.

```
df <- structure(list(
  col1 = c("First", "Frequency\nPercent", "CA", "TX"),
  col2 = c("Sex_3585", "Male", "298026\n5\n9", "45678\n15\n89"),
  col3 = c("", "Female", "57039\n10\n25", "64290\n100\n258")
),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,-4L))

                col1          col2            col3
1              First      Sex_3585                
2 Frequency\nPercent          Male          Female
3                 CA  298026\n5\n9   57039\n10\n25
4                 TX 45678\n15\n89 64290\n100\n258
```

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). In this case, please include the first few **raw** lines from the CSV file, enclosed in a code block. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I create a simple example of your data.

```
df <- structure(list(
  col1 = c("First", "Frequency\nPercent", "CA", "TX"),
  col2 = c("Sex_3585", "Male", "298026\n5\n9", "45678\n15\n89"),
  col3 = c("", "Female", "57039\n10\n25", "64290\n100\n258")
),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,-4L))

                col1          col2            col3
1              First      Sex_3585                
2 Frequency\nPercent          Male          Female
3                 CA  298026\n5\n9   57039\n10\n25
4                 TX 45678\n15\n89 64290\n100\n258
```

Second, after reading in the file with `read.csv`, one option is to separate the rows that have carriage returns (i.e., `\n`). Then, we can group by the first column and keep only the first row for each group.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(everything(), sep = "\n") %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==1)
```

**Output**

```
  col1      col2     col3    
  <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   
1 First     Sex_3585 ""      
2 Frequency Male     "Female"
3 Percent   Male     "Female"
4 CA        298026   "57039" 
5 TX        45678    "64290"
```